# Get live value of variable from another script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two scripts, new.py and test.py.

Test.py

```
import time
while True:
    x = "hello"
    time.sleep(1)
    x = "world"
    time.sleep(1)
```

new.py

```
import time
while True:
    import test    
    x = test.x

    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Now from my understanding this should print "hello" and a second later "world" all the time when executing new.py. 
It does not print anything, how can i fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for my previous answer... It was plain wrong. You need threads to do something like this... Or just one while loop. In a single thread you can't be in 2 non-nested while loops at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code below captures what you are asking. Here I simulate two scripts running independently (by using threads), then show how you can use [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shelve.html) to communicate between them. Note, there are likely much better ways to get to what you are after -- but if you absolutely must run the scripts independently, this will work for you.

Incidentally, any persistent source would do (such as a database).

```
import shelve
import time
import threading


def script1():
    while True:
        with shelve.open('my_store') as holder3:
            if holder3['flag'] is not None: break
            print('waiting')
            time.sleep(1)
    print("Done")


def script2():
    print("writing")
    with shelve.open('my_store') as holder2:
        holder2['flag'] = 1


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with shelve.open('my_store') as holder1:
        holder1['flag'] = None

    t = threading.Thread(target=script1)
    t.start()

    time.sleep(5)
    script2()

    t.join()
```

**Yields**:

```
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
writing
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

Test.py

```
import time
def hello():
    callList = ['hello', 'world']
    for item in callList:
        print item
        time.sleep(1)

hello()
```

new.py

```
from parent import hello

while True:
    hello()
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to state something. This is just a little program to show off my problem. I have a program somewhere, where a value can be either "this" or "that" based on some things that don't matter right now. I want the other program to do something once the value changes to "this".

Comment: Can you give a better description of the actual problem?

Comment: Essentially I have two programs running. The main program and a little program containing the variable "active". "active" depends on an IR barrier on my RPI. I want to inform my main program once "active" switches from true to false.

Comment: Not sure how to get you there with a live variable, sorry man